# New build won't start, but seem to have ruled out potential causes

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, power-supply

I'm working on a new build, and have never run into anything like this before.

I hit the power button, and... nothing. No case fans, no CPU fan, no PSU fans, no sounds, no beeps, no POST, no clicking, no ghostly wailing, no anguished screams (other than my own), no nothing.

First thought was that the PSU is DOA:

-Tested the PSU by bridging green & ground w/ a fan for load; PSU turns on fine

-Further tested the PSU by plugging it into a completely different build; works perfectly fine. Ok, so that rules out the PSU.

Motherboard:

-double/triple checked connections, memory seating, plugs/pins, CPU & heatsink seating, verified no bent pins on CPU, 24pin plugged in, 8+4pin plugged in, all connections fine

-removed from case and shorted the power pins for an out-of-case boot; still nothing

-reset CMOS, still nothing

-Thinking the MOBO was dead, **I replaced it and got a brand new motherboard. THE SAME THING HAPPENS WITH THE NEW ONE!** Barring the possibility of getting 2 DOA motherboards in a row, the motherboard is ruled out.

The only other components that are even involved for a boot test are the CPU and memory...but if there was an issue with either of those, I'd still get SOMETHING from an attempted boot, wouldn't I? Some beeps? CPU fan trying to turn on? A stutter, or something?

I feel like I'm missing something obvious - anyone able to point me in the right direction?

> Original Motherboard: ASUS AM4 TUF Gaming X570-Plus ATX
>
> Replacement Motherboard: MSI MPG X570 Gaming Edge WiFi
>
> CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3700X
>
> Memory: Corsair LPX 32GB (2x16GB) 3200MHz C16 DDR4 DRAM
>
> PSU: CORSAIR RM650

Comment: The problem seems to be the PSU and/or the motherboard. What can be done is trying a different PSU in this system. Doing this would eliminate any chances of the mobo being broken which doesn’t seem to be the case.

Comment: Also, what I think might actually be the problem is the fact that even on pressing/shorting the power button, the mobo isn’t turning up. Maybe something to do with bios(not sure tho).

Comment: Have you figured out what was the issue?